# 127.0.0.1 Refused To Connect (Coded in Codecademy)

Tags: python-3.x, localhost, connection-refused

I am quite a beginner in coding, trying to complete a programming assignment focused on Python. I followed along with Tech with Tim's YouTube video about "Python Website Full Tutorial - Flask, Authentication, Databases & More".  Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI

I have followed the code exactly up until 13:36, where he accesses the website url (http://127.0.0.1:5000).  I have tried this, yet I got a 127.0.0.1 refused to connect error.

[image]

I have tried to follow many different tutorials on how to fix this error, but to no avail.
I tried:

- flushing the dns
- disabling the firewall (real pain)
- browser HSTS settings

I would have tried asking my teacher, but she already got lost when I tried to explain about front-end and back-end and claimed that I was "too advanced".  I can't ask the other groups either as it seems they might not have started coding yet at all, and my own group does not specialize in coding, more on simple interface designing.  In canva.

I am now starting to suspect that it might be a problem with the website I am using to code.  I am using codecademy's workspaces since we are only allowed to code online because my teacher does not want to download any files on her computer.  Should I perhaps change to another one instead?

I have downloaded pip yesterday and made sure I downloaded all of the necessary modules, but it doesn't help the problem.

This is the fourth day that I have been stuck on this on, and now I've really hit a brick wall.  I'm stuck, and I'm not sure what to do next.  I am no programmer, I don't think that I can even be classified as a decent one just yet.  I'm simply a student who is forced to learn by myself because I can't rely on my own class to teach me.

Comment: Instead of putting your answer in the question, better to consider putting your solution in an answer, and accept it, then the question is closed and no longer in the unanswered questions queue..  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken Ahh I'm sorry, I'll do just that now.  Thanks for telling me.  :'D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOW SOLVED by changing to VS Code instead, works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce what you have done.
It seems your URL is missing the port number.

[image: Accessing webpage without port number]

[image: Accessing webpage with port number]
Solution: Append the port number after the URL like:

```
127.0.0.1:5000
```

Hope that solves your problem

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering!  It makes me very grateful for the fact that some people are willing to answer my questions.  I have tried to do as you suggested actually, with the port number before I asked this question.  I tried it again anyways for good measure, but it still didn't work.  Any other suggestions perhaps?  I appreciate it once again.